# Using Spring Data require distinct record on base of Foreign Key and Order BY value

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Sorry if someone already asked this question because after a lot of search I don't find it.

Currently using SpringData with Java 14, and right now facing the issue of Distinct record on Basis of Foreign-key along with Order BY.

I have two Table Table

- Product Category ( ID, name)
- Product ( ID, ProductCategoryID, price )

**Product Category**

[image]

**Product Table**

[image]

By using SpringData, following below is expected response and  I have to show Distinct Product by ProductCategory and Order by Price

**Expected Response**

[image]

As per Expected response I need those record where ProductCategory ID should be Distinct and each Distinct Product having higher price value.

Comment: Seems to me that one option is to write native query, and the other is to do it in the code (using Streams, loops, whatever you like). It all depends on the amount of data you're expecting to have.

Comment: I don't want to play with Streams

Comment: Then go with the native query. After writing native query, you'll see if it's possible to convert in into JPQL query.